# Normal mode representation for periodic boundary conditions

Tags: matrices, mathematical-physics, diagonalization, symplectic-linear-algebra, hamilton-equations

In order to decouple the equation of a chain of coupled harmonic oscillator I need to considerate the normal mode basis, here my Hamiltonian:
$$H = \sum_{i=0}^{N-1}\frac{p_i^2}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}(q_{i+1} - q_i)^2$$
In my problem I have $N$ particles with periodic boundary conditions, so $q_0=q_N$.

First method:

Now I can rewrite $H$ as $H = \frac{1}{2}z^TCz$ where $z = (p_0,p_1,\dots,p_{N-1},q_0,q_1,\dots,q_{N-1})$ so $C$ is

$$C = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & A\\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

where $1$ is the identity and $A$ is the following one:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
 2 & -1 & 0 & \dots & \dots & 0 & -1 \\
 -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & \dots & \dots & 0\\
 0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & \dots & 0\\
 \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots\\
 0 & \dots & 0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0\\
 0 & \dots & \dots & 0 & -1 & 2 & -1\\
-1 & 0 & \dots & \dots & 0 & -1 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Now in order to solve the problem I write down Hamilton equations

$$\dot{p_i}=-\frac{\partial{H}}{\partial{q_i}}=-2q_i+q_{i+1}+q_{i-1}$$
$$\dot{q_i}=\frac{\partial{H}}{\partial{p_i}}=p_i$$

So the problem to solve is given by

$$\dot{z}=JCz$$

where $J$ is a matrix given ($1$ is the identity matrix) by

$$J = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
-1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

To solve the problem I need to dyagonalize the $JC$ matrix:

$$M^{-1}(JC)M = \Lambda$$

And can be shown that the matrix $M$ is symplectic such that $M^TJM=J$.

---

Now how can I connect this with the normal modes? I think I understood that the normal modes are eigenvectors of the $JC$ matrix, am I supposed to know how to easily diagonalize this matrix with generic dimension? Where can I find infomation about how to diagonalize this matrix in generic dimension in order to obtain the eigenvectors?

---

On the other hand...

Secons method:

I only can find information online about how to obtain the normal modes with this method I'll show:

Given the Hamiltonian I can write the equation of motion:

$$\ddot{q}_j = -2q_j + q_{j+1} + q_{j-1}$$

Now I can make this ansatz: $q_l = A_le^{il\Omega}$, and if I insert this ansatz in the equation I obtain

$$-\Omega A_j = A_{i-1} - 2A_j + A_{j+1}$$

so if I suppose for $A_l = ae^{i\phi l}$ then $\Omega(\phi) = 2sin(\frac{\phi}{2})$

So $q_l = \mathfrak Re \left( a(\phi)e^{i(l\phi+\Omega(\phi)t)} \right)$

Now if I impose that $q_0 = q_{N}$  I obtain that $\phi = \frac{\pi k}{N}$ and $\Omega = 2\sin(\frac{\pi k}{2N})$, so I obtain:

$$q_l = \mathfrak Re \left(\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}ae^{i(\frac{\pi kl}{N} + \Omega t)} \right)$$

And this is the normal mode representation. I am totally confused.

---

How can I connect this method with the "algebric vision" that I mentioned before? I can't find anything that satisfies me online. The second method is somehow disconnected from the first for me, because I don't understand how my ansatz gave me the eigenvectors of the matrix. I don't know if I am totally wrong about this desire of link this two methods, If you know a book where I can follow a step by step indication to write my problem in normal modes with periodic boundary condition can you please indicate me the title? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please break into sections. One should not have to read the whole thing to find the actual question.

Comment: I need it to be like this because I would like to know how to connect this two points of view and often people tell me in this website to be more specific, sorry for the inconvenience about the length.  Maybe do you know how can I connect the two methods?

Comment: I didn't get to methods. I was trying to find where matrices $A$ and $J$ are defined. Disrespecting the readers' time is not the optimal path. Ideally, the actual question should be well-defined and require less than 5 seconds to read. If one is interested, one can read the whole question.

Comment: I don't think I should force you to be interested if you are not. :)

Comment: You don't get it. It's your job to sell your question. I told you how to improve it to reach the widest audience possible, and you don't seem to care. If you enjoy having your questions ignored by most, then you're on the right path.

Comment: No I got it, I simply need my question to be like this because if I don't explain the two different things it is not clear. If nobody wants to read more than 5 lines is a bit depressing